# Get the host name from within the docker container from Python program

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, docker

As per my application requirement, I need to get the server IP and the server name from the python program. But my application is resides inside the specific docker container on top of the Ubuntu.

I have tried like the below

```
import os
os.system("hostname")  # to get the hostname
os.system("hostname -i") # to get the host ip
```

Output:
`2496c9ab2f4a172.*.*.*`

But it is giving the host name as a it's residing docker containerid and the host_ip as it's private ip address as above. I need the hostname as it is the server name. But when I type these above commands in the terminal I am able to get result what I want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You won't be able to get the host system's name this way. To get it, you can either define an environment variable, either in your Dockerfile, or when running your container (-e option). Alternatively, you can mount your host `/etc/hostname` file into the container, or copy it...

This is an example run command I use to set the environment variable HOSTNAME to the host's hostname within the container:

```
docker run -it -e "HOSTNAME=$(cat /etc/hostname)" <image> <cmd>
```

In python you can then run `os.environ["HOSTNAME"]` to get the hostname. 
As far as the IP address goes, I use this command to get retrieve it from a running container:

```
route -n | awk '/UG[ \t]/{print $2}'
```

You will have to install route to be able to use this command. It is included in the package net-tools. `apt-get install net-tools`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I have tried to add the hostname to the environmental variable to running container. It is not accepting my command. my command is __docker run <containername> -e HOST_HOSTNAME = 'hostname'__ And coming to the IP, i can get it using the ipgetter module like __ipgetter.myip()__

Comment: PyCharm is also being a smart ass and has escaped the `$(cat /etc/hostname)` part. So in the container, when I type `os.environ["HOSTNAME"]` I get `$(cat /etc/hostname)` as a string. *Facepalm*

Answer (score 0):

An alternative might be the following:

ENV:

```
NODENAME: '{{.Node.Hostname}}'
```

This will get you the Hostname of the Node, where the container is running as an environment variable (tested on Docker-Swarm / CoreOs Stable).

Comment: This worked great for me.  I can get the `a3fc2...` style name from `os.gethostname()`, but this gave me the friendly name (e.g. `manager-1`).  Not sure why it was downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

you can go for something like this:

```
def determine_docker_host_ip_address():
    cmd = "ip route show"
    import subprocess
    process = subprocess.Popen(cmd.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    output, error = process.communicate()
    return str(output).split(' ')[2]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import os

os.uname().nodename
```

Comment: Could you please add a bit more description, either why/how the code works or any information about the module

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can get the hostname on Linux/Unix systems by using the `os` package:

```py
import os

os.uname().nodename
```

However this won't work on systems like Windows, as `os.uname` is not available there.

Instead, use the `platform` package, as it works on all systems/platforms:

```py
import platform

platform.node()
```